# mysql command inside mysql container hung forever

Tags: mysql, docker

On my centos host, running mysql command through docker exec is hung forever:

```
$ docker exec mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=passwd123 < mysql.backup.sql
```

The mysql DB is accessible using mysqlworkbench just fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following for backup

`docker exec mysql /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=passwd123 DATABASE > backup.sql`

Instead of mysql you should use mysqldump ( Mysqldump is a command-line utility that is used to generate the logical backup of the MySQL database. )

If your purpose is restore, then

`cat backup.sql | docker exec -i mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=passwd123 DATABASE`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing -i parameter in my original command.

This command works perfectly:

```
$ $ docker exec -i mysql /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=passwd123 < mysql.backup.sql
```